# "Publishing failed" generic, undescriptive error message when attempting to publish Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using Visual Studio to develop my C# Azure Functions. I attempt to publish my Azure Function to the cloud, and encounter this message in the screenshot. My Azure Function App has created and in the started state, so that is not the issue.

What is the cause of this error? Or is there any other way to get a more descriptive error message?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being that I was using `#if` in the Azure function in this way:

```
namespace Common.Utils
{
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    #if DEBUG
    using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
    using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
    #endif
    .....
```

While the above worked in both Debug and Release modes while I was testing locally, it didn't work in the cloud.

Comment: I removed my DEBUG, it made no difference and I still couldn't deploy

Answer (score 1):

1. I published it to local folder
2. Logged into functionapp.scm.azurewebsites.net
3. Deleted all contents in site/wwwroot
4. replaced the contents with the contents from published folder.

it works!

Comment: This is a potentially valid workaround but it doesn't really answer the question, which was centered on how to get details on what's preventing the publish from working. The user who posted the question has already traced and fixed the error some time ago, so your answer doesn't really provide any additional benefit to this question.